# Buscar numero de tarjeta de credito en un input o textbox, posterior a esto removerlo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Necesito validar si en un `<input>` o `<textarea>` existe un numero de tarjeta de credito, posterior a esto removerlo o reemplazarlo por XXXX por cuestiones de seguridad en un chat que estoy desarrollando.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hi, this is StackOverflow in spanish, Would you mind translating your question to spanish, please?

Comment: The oficial lenguage of the site is Spanish

Comment: Buenos dias, Necesito validar si existe un numero de tarjeta de credito en un input o textbox, posterior a esto removerlo.

Comment: No lo pongas como comentario, edita tu pregunta y tradúcela al español.

Comment: Ya, Gracias por las sugerencias !

Comment: ¿qué haz intentado hasta el momento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar una serie de Regex para detectar si el numero de tarjeta es de algún tipo conocido (los números pueden variar en cantidad de dígitos y prefijos) y luego reemplazar el valor del input por una cadena de texto tipo 'xxxx' y luego el numero.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo, si soportas otras tarjetas, [acá tenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231321/2573335) una lista de expresiones regulares para validar la fuente.

```js
function getCardType(cardNo) {
  var cards = {
    "American Express": /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,
    "Mastercard": /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
    "Visa": /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/
  };
  
  for(var card in cards) {
    if (cards[card].test(cardNo)) {
      return card;
    }
  }
  
  return undefined;
}

$('input').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val().trim();
  
  var cardType = getCardType(value);
  
  if (!cardType) {
    alert('tarjeta invalida');
  } else {
    alert('tarjeta tipo:' + cardType);
    $(this).val(Array(value.length-4).join("X")+value.substring(value.length-4));
  }      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Ejemplo usar: 4910123412341234 (Visa)
<input type="text">
```

## Edicion

En el caso especifico tuyo, donde el numero de tarjeta esta embebido dento del texto te dejo este ejemplo, que es parecido, lo que cambia es que las regex no tienen los caracteres de inicio y fin de linea por ovias razones. Si tienes que traer alguna regex del link antes mencionado, seria conveniente reemplazar el `^` y `$` por `\b` para que pueda encontrar el numero de trajeta dentro del texto como una palabra independiente.

```js
function extractCardInfo(text) {
  var cards = {
    "American Express": /\b3[47][0-9]{13}\b/,
    "Mastercard": /\b5[1-5][0-9]{14}\b/,
    "Visa": /\b4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?\b/
  };
  
  for(var card in cards) {
    if (cards[card].test(text)) {
      var arr = text.match(cards[card]);
      return { type: card, number: arr[0] };
    }
  }
  
  return undefined;
}

$('textarea').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  var card = extractCardInfo(value);
  
  if (card) {
    alert('tarjeta tipo:' + card.type);
    var nuevoValor = Array(card.number.length-4).join("X")+card.number.substring(card.number.length-4);
    $(this).val(value.replace(card.number, nuevoValor));
  }      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Ejemplo, editar y hacer tab para ver como funciona este es el numero de tarjeta 4910123412341234 (Visa) salu2
</textarea>
```

Comment: Muy útil, gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte pero en el campo de texto van a existir muchos caracteres, es una descripcion .. puedes ver la imagen descriptiva de la pregunta

Comment: @user1622966 hice unos cambios, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Para poner los valores con una XX puedes utilizar:

```
str = str.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "X");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente te mostrará los últimos 4 dígitos.
Puedes ver más información [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/hL4vY1/1)

Y si quieres validar el textbox en Javascript lo puedes hacer así:

```or-tag-here
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validar() {
        //obteniendo el valor que se puso en campo text del formulario
        miCampoTexto = document.getElementById("miCampo").value;
        //la condición
        if (miCampoTexto.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<form action="mipagina.php" onsubmit="return validar()">
    <input type="text" id="miCampo" name="miCampo"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta ... El problema es cuando escriben teléfonos o números de documento, necesito uno que coincida con el patron de tarjeta de credito.

Comment: puedes ver la imagen descriptiva de la pregunta